Unconventional Boundary Conditions
A follow up from the previous question
References: similar question, paper
Constants
My domain is $\Omega$ = Rectangle[ {xmin, ymin} , {xmax,ymax}]
xmax >> ymax, xmin << ymin
Assume all other constants as 1
Differential equations are:
$\nabla _{\{x,y\}}\cdot \{\text{Jx}(x,y),\text{Jy}(x,y)\}=0$
$ \text{D$\nu$ }^2 \nabla _{\{x,y\}}^2\{\text{Jx}(x,y),\text{Jy}(x,y)\}+\frac{\sigma_{0}}{e}\nabla _{\{x,y\}}\phi (x,y)=\{\text{Jx}(x,y),\text{Jy}(x,y)\}$
These differential equations solve for electron hydrodynamic flow in a 2D geometry.
Here, $Jx$ and $Jy$ are the x and y components of the Linearized steady state particle current density $\vec{J}$ and $\phi(x,y)$ is the electric potential.
Boundary Conditions
There are some Dirichlet Boundary Conditions that I can implement, but there is one condition that I am unable to, namely:
At y = ymin,   $ Jx^{(0,1)}(x,y) + Jy^{(1,0)}(x,y) = -\frac{Jx(x,y)}{l_{b}}$
At y = ymax,   $ Jx^{(0,1)}(x,y) + Jy^{(1,0)}(x,y) = \frac{Jx(x,y)}{l_{b}}$
Here, $l_{b}$ is a constant called as the slip-length
Implementation in Mathematica
SlipBCs = {
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)] . \({{{0, 1}, {1, 0}} . {Jx[x, y], Jy[x, y]}}\)\) == Jx[x,y]/lb /.y->ymin,
\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)] . \({{{0, 1}, {1, 0}} . {Jx[x, y], Jy[x, y]}}\)\) == -(Jx[x,y]/lb) /.y->ymax,

DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x,y]==0.,x==xmax ],
DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x,y]==0,x==xmin],
DirichletCondition[Jx[x,y]==0.,x==xmin || x==xmax],
DirichletCondition[Jy[x,y]==JyPlus,y==ymax],
DirichletCondition[Jy[x,y]==JyMinus,y==ymin]

};

solN = NDSolve[{eqn1,eqn2,SlipBCs},{\[Phi],Jx,Jy},{x,y}\[Element]\[CapitalOmega],Method->{"FiniteElement","InterpolationOrder"->{\[Phi]->1,Jx->2,Jy->2},"MeshOptions"->{"MaxCellMeasure"->0.0005}}];

Here, JyPlus and JyMinus mimic the current probes.
My questions are
Can I implement NeumannValue in this context, if so, then how do I do so?
The output I get after running the code is:
NDSolve::fembdnl: The dependent variable in {(Jx^(0,1))[x,-5.]+(Jy^(1,0))[x,-5.]}==Jx in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[{(Jx^(0,1))[x,-5.]+(Jy^(1,0))[x,-5.]}==Jx,y==-5.] needs to be linear.

TLDR:
EDIT - 01

How do I implement NeumannValue in Mathematica for the boundary condition mentioned?
How do I implement NeumannValue in general, like, if there are 3 coupled PDEs and 3 variables to solve, and I have neumann boundary condition for one of them at some edge, and not the whole boundary, how do I do so? I couldn't understand the Mathematica documentation page on NeumannValue much after reading it, hence the question.


Could you show parameters $l_p,D,\nu, \sigma_0,\epsilon$ and JyPlus,JyMinus,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax?

@AlexTrounev
The parameters l_b, D_nu, sigma0, e are 1.
JyPlus = 0;
JyMinus = -i/e DiracDelta[x-x0] + i/e DiracDelta[x+x0];
Here, i is the current, and is 1, x0 = 2
xmax = 100, xmin = -100
ymax = 10, ymin = -10
My only concern is the boundary conditions with l_b

Thank you. Please note that we can't use DiracDelta[] in numerical model.

@AlexTrounev yes, I have modified it into a piecewise unit box function
JyMinus = Piecewise[{{1, y == ymin}}]*(-i/e Piecewise[{{1, Abs[x - x0] < 0.5}}] + i/e Piecewise[{{1, Abs[x + x0] < 0.5}}])

I am unable to understand how to implement NeumannValue in general, if there is a good resource, do share.
Example 1: If there are 3 equations and 3 variables to solve, and I have a neumann boundary conditions for one of the variables, how do I add it in the code?  Such questions, I am unable to answer.
